# Python - Calculating Percent of Total in Pivot Tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, percentage

I have a dataframe that I converted to a pivot table using pd.pivot_table method and a sum aggregate function:

```
    SM_waterfall = df.query('type == ["SM"] & condition == ["Carrier Damaged","Customer Damaged","Unknown"]').pivot_table(index=["shipdate"], columns=["completeddate"],aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name="Total")

    amount                    
completeddate    2018-8   2018-9     Total
shipdate                                  
2018-6          8430.25     0.00   8430.25
2018-7           840.24  1018.39   1858.63
2018-8          1011.10   340.82   1351.92
2018-9             0.00  2463.25   2463.25
Total          10281.59  3822.46  14104.05

amount      
completeddate   2018-8  2018-9  Total
shipdate            
2018-6         1.00000  0.00000 1.00000
2018-7         0.45207  0.54793 1.00000
2018-8         0.74790  0.25210 1.00000
2018-9        0.00000   1.00000 1.00000
Total        0.72898    0.27102 1.00000
```

I want to convert all of the values within the pivot to % of last column such that  dataframe appears as shown in bottom df. I'm very new to this and have seen code that calculates based off of sum columns, but not rows.

Comment: Hi mrspacely ... welcome to SO. Can you repost the data? i tried to reformat it but, was confused. If you can post what the data is, format it correctly, and an example of what you want it to be, we can take a look. Thanks!

Comment: came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064752/pandas-pivot-table-percentage-of-row-calculation-for-non-numeric-values?rq=1. could you explain to me why this works? SM_waterfall.div( SM_waterfall.iloc[:,-1], axis=0 )